# Docker Solr: Cannot index local data folder

Tags: solr, docker

I am using Docker in OS X. Just got the docker container "solr" from the official repo [1]. The container is up and running. Been following their instructions and created a "core" like so:

```
$ docker exec -it --user=solr my_solr bin/solr create_core -c gettingstarted
```

Afterwards I wanted to index a folder containing pdf files like so:

```
$ docker exec -it --user=solr my_solr bin/post -c gettingstarted ./some_pdfs/
```

I get an error saying:

```
Unrecognized argument: ./some_pdfs/

If this was intended to be a data file, it does not exist relative to /opt/solr
```

I know that if I ssh into my docker container, there is an /opt/solr folder. But my intention is to index files on my local hard disk. How can I do this?

[1] https://hub.docker.com/r/library/solr/

---

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I cannot index local files from my laptop using this docker container like above.

I followed instructions in the excellent book "Pro Docker" from Deepak Vohra and copied a test PDF file to the docker container like so:

```
sudo docker cp mydocument.pdf 8065379d1f16:/opt/solr/mydocument.pdf
```

then logged into that docker container like so:

```
docker exec -it –user=solr my_solr bash
```

and started the bin/post command from docker container. That worked.